# Edit text wrap points on photo, using "tight" wrap. Can't see text under old wrap points

Tags: microsoft-word

I inserted a photo in my WORD doc. I selected edit wrap points and moved the border of the lower right side of the photo to make more space for text. I set the wrap to tight. As I typed the text beside the photo it correctly followed the new edited lines, but I could not see the text in the newly created space. I did not begin to see the text until it went outside of the original photo  border, then the text was visible. How can I make the text in the newly edited wrap points area visible? It was wrapping to the newly edited points, but I could not see the text beneath the old photo border.